# Existence of a method in JavaScript: Checking for truthy sufficient?

Tags: javascript

If I like to test if an object has a specific method: Would the following code work reliable?

```
const obj = {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
}

if (obj.add) {
    console.log(obj.add(9, 3));
}

if (obj.sub) {
    console.log(obj.sub(8, 2));
}
```

Or would it potentially fail? If so: For what reason?

And if it isn't sufficient: What should I use instead?

Comment: your code works. your object does not contain other own properties. what propblem are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to call the method, you should check to see it's actually a method first. If it's a non-function property, what you're doing will result in a TypeError.

```js
const obj = {
  add: true
}

if (obj.add) {
    console.log(obj.add(9, 3));
}

if (obj.sub) {
    console.log(obj.sub(8, 2));
}
```

So:

```js
const obj = {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  },
  badProp: true
}
const verify = arg => typeof arg === 'function';
if (verify(obj.add)) {
    console.log(obj.add(9, 3));
}

if (verify(obj.sub)) {
    console.log(obj.sub(8, 2));
}

if (verify(obj.badProp)) {
    obj.badProp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof()` is a way to check weather a var is a function or anything else.

```
if (typeof obj.add === 'function') {
    console.log(obj.add(9, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead if checking for just name. I would suggest checking type too.
Refer below code for same

```
const obj = {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
}
if (typeof obj.add === "function") { 
    console.log(obj.add(9, 3));
}

if (typeof obj.sub === "function") {
    console.log(obj.sub(8, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this .Check if `object key` is a function,

```js
const obj = {
  add:function (a, b) {
    return a + b
  },
   sub:function (a, b) {
    return a - b
  }
}

if (typeof obj.add === 'function') {
    console.log(obj.add(9, 3));
}

if (typeof obj.sub === 'function') {
    console.log(obj.sub(8, 2));
}
```